# Need to pass dynamic password to PoolBase class of Hikari CP

Tags: connection-pooling, hikaricp

We need to pass password dynamically to Hikari CP so that whenever we change password of database our service should be able to consume it without restart.
I have seen that in PoolBase class of Hikari CP we have `newConnection()` method where we take password from Hikari Config object.

snippet taken form PooBase Class

```
private Connection newConnection() throws Exception
    {
       final long start = currentTime();
 
       Connection connection = null;
       try {
          String username = config.getUsername();
          String password = config.getPassword();
 
          connection = (username == null) ? dataSource.getConnection() : dataSource.getConnection(username, password);
          if (connection == null) {
             throw new SQLTransientConnectionException("DataSource returned null unexpectedly");
          }
 
          setupConnection(connection);
          lastConnectionFailure.set(null);
          return connection;
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
          if (connection != null) {
             quietlyCloseConnection(connection, "(Failed to create/setup connection)");
          }
          else if (getLastConnectionFailure() == null) {
             logger.debug("{} - Failed to create/setup connection: {}", poolName, e.getMessage());
          }
 
          lastConnectionFailure.set(e);
          throw e;
       }
       finally {
          // tracker will be null during failFast check
          if (metricsTracker != null) {
             metricsTracker.recordConnectionCreated(elapsedMillis(start));
          }
       }
    }
```

How can I override `getPassword()` method so that it can use my custom method to get password which will bring password from vault.

Comment: Did you found a way?